# How can i run the webpage, which cannot display in chrome and can display in firefox, in phantomjs

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I have a question about the selenium with phantomjs issue.
When I used firefox to open the website by below code. The program can be execute successfully.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
log.debug("Open Browser successfully...");
driver.get(the url);
```

However, when i changed the web drive to phantomjs, the driver cannot open the url. When i tried to get the page sources, the page sources is the empty html and with the java script error code within the HTML.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: multiple points
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1084)
    at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:475)
    at com.tibco.wfc.util.ServletUtils.getIsBrowserVersionOk(ServletUtils.java:108)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.com.tibco.administrator.LoginPaneUI_jsp._jspService(LoginPaneUI_jsp.java:87)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:371)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:565)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:493)
    at com.tibco.wfc.JspComponentUI.display(JspComponentUI.java:154)
    at com.tibco.wfc.AbstractComponent.display(AbstractComponent.java:194)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.com.tibco.wfc.AbstractFrameUI_jsp._jspService(AbstractFrameUI_jsp.java:236)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:371)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:565)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:493)
    at com.tibco.wfc.JspComponentUI.display(JspComponentUI.java:154)
    at com.tibco.wfc.AbstractComponent.display(AbstractComponent.java:194)
    at com.tibco.wfc.AbstractFrame.display(AbstractFrame.java:157)
    at com.tibco.wfc.FrameManager.a(FrameManager.java:263)
    at com.tibco.wfc.FrameManager.service(FrameManager.java:142)
    at com.tibco.administrator.AdministratorServlet.service(AdministratorServlet.java:957)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.InvokerServlet.serveRequest(InvokerServlet.java:420)
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.InvokerServlet.doGet(InvokerServlet.java:134)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:627)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:879)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: multiple points
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:500)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:413)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:565)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:493)
    at com.tibco.wfc.JspComponentUI.display(JspComponentUI.java:154)
    at com.tibco.wfc.AbstractComponent.display(AbstractComponent.java:194)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.com.tibco.wfc.AbstractFrameUI_jsp._jspService(AbstractFrameUI_jsp.java:236)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:371)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:565)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:493)
    at com.tibco.wfc.JspComponentUI.display(JspComponentUI.java:154)
    at com.tibco.wfc.AbstractComponent.display(AbstractComponent.java:194)
    at com.tibco.wfc.AbstractFrame.display(AbstractFrame.java:157)
    at com.tibco.wfc.FrameManager.a(FrameManager.java:263)
    at com.tibco.wfc.FrameManager.service(FrameManager.java:142)
    at com.tibco.administrator.AdministratorServlet.service(AdministratorServlet.java:957)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.InvokerServlet.serveRequest(InvokerServlet.java:420)
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.InvokerServlet.doGet(InvokerServlet.java:134)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:627)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:879)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Finally, i found that, chrome cannot open the web url, only firefox and IE can open the web url.
However, i observed this behavior, how can i solve this issue in phantomJs?
Many thanks.

Comment: try removing this line from code `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Comment: The exception has no stack trace related to selenium here? Please add a try catch and dump the complete exception that you get in your code

Comment: @GaurangShah Thanks for your help, after remove the line, still not work.

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thanks, there is no exception followed by selenium. But the situation is, Firefox can open the webpage, but the webpage cannot be opened after changed to phantomjs. So, i guess there are some webpages which can open in firefox but cannot in phantomjs. So, how can i use Phantomjs to fix the issue?